# Redirect results in loop. How can I solve this?

Tags: php

I am a System Administrator trying to host a small website in my private time. As a start I am using Wordpress.

Currently I am trying to achieve that when someone presses a link, he/she gets redirected to a random page.

This should be easy as my pages are something like website.com/network1 , website.com/network2 etc. In this case I want to create a function that generates a number and replaces the number. So in this case it would look like website.com/network$random_number.

I've tried Googling this and I've found a script that should do exactly this: [Going to a Random page PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498279/going-to-a-random-page-php)
Funny thing is that it's on the same website!

Unfortunately when using this code in a file called 'random.php' located in ./dump/ it will result in being redirected to: /random.phpdump/random.phpdump/random.phpdump/random.php (so a loop).

The code I am currently using is:

```
<?php
    //from http://php.net/header
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

    $random_number = rand(1,5);
    header( 'Location: https://website.com/network$random_number', true /* overwrite */, 303 );
?>
```

How can I change this to get it working and what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: change singe quotes to double

Comment: Or `'Location: https://website.com/network'  . $random_number`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)